# raise exception with set(list).difference and conditional statement

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
List1 = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H]
list2 = [A,B,C,D]
```

I want to make sure that list1 contains at least all the elements of list2 (order doesn't matter). If not I want to raise an Exception.

```
set = set(list2).difference(List1)

if set != "":
    raise Exception('Missing required columns',set)
```

however printing `set` variable return this: `set()`. I'm not sure how to interpret it. I was hoping for a empty string. How can I build my conditional statement against this? I feel like I'm not doing this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with the logic.

1. You are assigning `set` to the result of `set.difference`. This is probably undesirable.
2. You are comparing a `set` (as returned by `set.difference`) to a `str` (`""`) so the logic will always raise the Exception.

Perhaps try:

```py
diffset = set(list2).difference(List1)
if diffset:
    raise Exception(f'Missing required columns {diffset}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```py
>>> l1 = list('ABCABDDCB')
>>> l1
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'C', 'B']
>>> l2 = list('ABCD')
>>> l2
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> set(l1) == set(l2)
True
```

---

```py
>>> l2 = list('ABCDE')
>>> l2
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
>>> set(l1) == set(l2)
False
```

---

```
>>> if not set(l1) == set(l2):
...     raise Exception('Missing required columns',set)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
Exception: ('Missing required columns', <class 'set'>)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` function:

```
if not all(e in List1 for e in List2):
    raise Exception('Missing required columns {}'.format(set(list2).difference(List1)))
```

Or `any` function:

```py
if any(e not in List1 for e in List2):
    raise Exception('Missing required columns {}'.format(set(list2).difference(List1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You check for the wrong data type. `set.difference()` returns a `set`, not a `str`. So in your `if` statement, you have to check against an empty set (`set()`) or check it's length with `len(set)`. One thing, however - avoid naming variables/function with names already existing in global scope (such as the built-in `set`). It can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this maybe:

```
if not (set(list2) <= set(List1)):
    raise Exception('Missing required columns',set)
```